# registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION))

Tags: android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging

I am getting the following error in the following code.
Any help in solving this. Also I want to details about Android GCM regarding code functionality.
[image: Screenshot of the Error]

> registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new
>   IntentFilter(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));

```
    // Get GCM registration id
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

    // Check if regid already presents
    if (regId.equals("")) {
        // Registration is not present, register now with GCM
        GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
    } else {
        // Device is already registered on GCM
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
            // Skips registration.
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already registered with GCM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
            // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
            // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.
            final Context context = this;
            mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    // Register on our server
                    // On server creates a new user
                    ServerUtilities.register(context, name, email, regId);
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    mRegisterTask = null;
                }

            };
            mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Receiving push messages
 * */
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
        WakeLocker.acquire(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: which class owns DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION ? have u imported it? or maybe you are required to make your own Intent perhaps?

Comment: what i mean is according to the image you've provided, DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION and SENDER_ID seems undefined. shouldn't it be defined in your class as maybe like `static final String SENDER_ID = "903913289319";` and `static final String DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION =           "com.androidhive.pushnotifications.DISPLAY_MESSAGE";`

Comment: yes, I got it. Thanks.